# Noncommutative Fredholm operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, index-theory, noncommutative-topology

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra and $F:H_A\rightarrow H_A$ a Fredholm operator on the standard Hilbert $A$-module $H_A:=l^2(A)$. Is it true that $\mbox{ker}(F)$ and $\mbox{coker}(F)$ are finitely generated Hilbert $A$-modules?

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise by what "Fredholm" means here?  Do you mean that F is an adjointable operator on $H_A$ with finite-dimensional kernel and cokernel?  Or do you have in mind a definition more "adapted" to Hilbert $C^*$-modules, such as [definition on nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Hilbert+module#fredholm_operators)?

Comment: @matthew Right, I mean Fredholm in the sense of Hilbert $C^*$-module theory...that is, $F$ is an adjointable operators that is invertible modulo compact operators in $K(H_A)$.

Comment: +1 for your question.To be honest I was thinking to question somewhat similar to your interesting question: I submited the following note to a journal then referee inform me the shift operator is not Fredholm on $\ell^1(A)$ . Then I was thinking of consideration of the later as an $A$ module rather than a complex vector space

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4196

Comment: After that the journal reject my paper with  indication that the shift operator is not fredholm, I had  email communication with the editor and wrote him "what about consideration $A$ module structure rather than complex vector space.

Comment: So your question, is a motivation to think about a fredholm index approach to the Fundamental theorem of algebra in the context of Banavh algebras. This fredholm index approach to  FTA for usual polynomials is very straightforward because the shoft operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{C}$ is obviously a fredholm operator of index $-1$.aThanks again for your very interesting answer.

Comment: .my apology I correct the previous comment: "for your very interesting question"

Answer (score 2):

The image of Fredholm operator on a Hilbert module is not always closed. If it is not closed, then cokernel is certainly not finitely generated. A simple example is when $A=C_0(\mathbb{R})$ and $F$ is the diagonal matrix $\rm{diag}(x,1,1,...):H_A\to H_A$.

However, the following two statements are true

1. If the image of $F$ is closed then kernel and cokernel are finitely generated.
2. For any Fredholm operator $F:H_A\to H_A$ there is a compact perturbation $F+K$ ($K$ is a compact operator) whose image is closed.

See Higson, A primer on KK-theory, Theorem 3.21.